# How can i make a Bootstrap Alert Box transparent without affecting the text inside the box?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a alert box slightly transparent, without affecting the text inside the box, but i have no idea how i should implement this.

My CSS File looks like this

```
 .cookiealert 
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height:8%; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGBA color values are an extension of RGB color values with an alpha channel - which specifies the opacity for a color.

An RGBA color value is specified with: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha). The alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque).

```
.cookiealert 
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height:8%; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);/* red with opacity */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found an answer myself

```
.cookiealert {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height:8%; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055)
    /*opacity: 0.7;*/
  }
```